# Escape or insert after last closing div in a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom, insert

I am trying to insert more markup after a closing `</div>` that already exist as a string. I currently have the following markup below and would like to insert after my closing div. I've tried using pop then replace and not having any luck.

Tried this but no luck:

```
const myString = '<div class='wrapper'><h1 >Demo</h1><div class='container--inner'><div class='row'><div class='column'><div class='left'><p>Contrary to popular belief</p></div></div></div></div>'
const newDiv = myString.split(' ').pop();
myString.replace(newDiv, `hello`);
```

What i am being returned:

```
<div class='wrapper'><h1>One Column</h1><div class='container--inner'><div class='row'><div class='column'><div class='left'><p>Contrary to popular belief, hello
```

Current markup I am getting back as a string:

```
<div class='wrapper'><h1 >Demo</h1><div class='container--inner'><div class='row'><div class='column'><div class='left'><p>Contrary to popular belief</p></div></div></div></div> <----Insert after this closing div.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, **the easiest one would be appending the new string to the previous one by using add (`+`) operator**, then you can simply append all of it to other elements in DOM like body.

Also, you need to keep in mind you can't use the same quote (single or double) for wrapping your whole element and wrapping your class within the HTML structure. So you should either use [backticks (template literals)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or different quote for them.

Here is how it can be done by this simple approach:

```js
let myString = "<div class='wrapper'><h1>Demo</h1><div class='container--inner'><div class='row'><div class='column'><div class='left'><p>Contrary to popular belief</p></div></div></div></div>"

myString += 'hello'
console.log(myString)

document.body.innerHTML = myString
```

---

You can also **do this more readable and cleaner with template literals** like this:

```js
let myString = "<div class='wrapper'><h1>Demo</h1><div class='container--inner'><div class='row'><div class='column'><div class='left'><p>Contrary to popular belief</p></div></div></div></div>"

myString = `${myString}hello`
console.log(myString)

document.body.innerHTML = myString
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the dom api instead of string parsing/replacing . i dont know after which div you want to put your markups but in order to give an example i will take the wrapper div and append to its end.

```js
const myString = `<div class='wrapper'><h1 >Demo</h1><div class='container--inner'><div class='row'><div class='column'><div class='left'><p>Contrary to popular belief</p></div></div></div></div>`

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = myString;
container.querySelector(".wrapper").append("hello");
console.log(container.innerHTML)
```